# Не могу сохранить связанные таблицы. Использую ActiveAndroid ORM

Tags: android

Я юзаю библиотеку ActiveAndroid. это ORM'ка. так вот возникли проблемы при сохранении. Есть класс, полями которого являются другие классы. Например класс User с полями  Human  и Info. я хочу сохранить User user; user.save();  и ожидаю, что ормка сама сохранит Human  и Info. Я даже нагуглил и нашел что для этого нужно делать так

```
@Column(name = "transactionList", onDelete = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE, onUpdate = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE)
```

но по факту это не работает. как правильно сохранить связаные таблицы?

Comment: А что в доках к этой ORM пишут по этому поводу?